# Adding list item in SharePoint List gives an error on date format

Tags: custom-list, splistitem, date-time, sharepoint-on-prem, datepicker

i have an issue with all my lists in SharePoint, giving error when adding an item to list "You must specify a valid date within the range of 1/1/1900 and 12/31/8900."

I have checked regional settings and language, but cant figure out how to fix this...any clue?

Thanks
reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by setting Reginal setting ---> locale to English (US). and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same date format as expected, in this case MM/DD/YYYY. Also check that you are passing in a DateTime value and not a string.